# Diffrence between two dirs?

Tags: command-line, tools, diff

I have two identical folders, but the are not identical(for example Java installation dir). One dir has one extra file and one file has been changed.

Is there any easy to use tool to check that or do I have to write complicated bash script for that?

P.S. I'm looking for command-line tool, but if you know any GUI tools please share the knowledge.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
diff -qr dir1 dir2 | sort
```

That will compare files in two directories.

If you're a sadist you can drop the `q` argument (and the `| sort` pipe) and you'll see all the differences between all the files... But the output is pretty hard to interpret like that.

If you do have a lot to handle, perhaps piping through `less` (just add `| less` to the command) will let you view it a little easier.

Answer (score 20):

`meld` is a good graphical diff frontend that will show you a side-by side listing of files. Install meld with Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or use these commands with the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install meld
meld dir1 dir2
```

[image: meld in action]

Answer (score 1):

As to GUI, [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) seems to be able to compare directories.

Comment: isnt it only for KDE?

Comment: The program uses QT and the KDE libraries. That means that those libraries need to be installed, but not that the entire KDE desktop must be present. Like all other programs based on those libraries, `kdiff3` works without problems on GNOME or other desktop environments.